# Compute single patient Z-Scores from atlas anatomical zone

Tags: neuroimaging, spm

I have one brain image from a single patient. I have a set of normal pateints. Both, single patient and normal patients are normalised to an SPM template and the NMI space.

I also have a brain atlas (AAL Atlas) in nii format.

I need to compute the Z-Scores for each region of the patient.

Which is the simplest procedure?